# Vaadin: Grid duplicates data

Tags: java, grid, vaadin

I wrote Grid, as shown in [example](https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/components/tutorial-flow-grid.html).

```
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    private final UserService userService;
    private Label label;
    private Grid<UserDto> grid;

    public MainView(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
        initComponents(userService);
    }

    private void initComponents(UserService userService) {
        initMainGrid(userService);
    }

    private void initMainGrid(UserService userService) {
        grid = new Grid<>(UserDto.class);

        grid.setItems(userService.getAll());

        grid.addColumn(UserDto::getId).setHeader("ID");
        grid.addColumn(UserDto::getUsername).setHeader("Имя пользователя");
        grid.addColumn(UserDto::getPassword).setHeader("Пароль");
        grid.addColumn(UserDto::getEmail).setHeader("email");
        grid.addColumn(UserDto::getPhone).setHeader("Телефон");
        grid.addColumn(UserDto::getActive).setHeader("Активен");

        add(grid);
    }
}
```

But data duplicates:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

As we see, data shows two times.

Please advice, what wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Passing `Class` object to `Grid` constructor

This constructor `grid = new Grid<>(UserDto.class);` will automatically add columns according to setters and getters of `UserDto` class.

## Not passing `Class` object to `Grid` constructor

If you want to configure columns using `addColumn` method, you need to instantiate `Grid` using `grid = new Grid<>();` without passing `UserDto.class`.

Answer (score 5):

Small addition to [the correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59569467/642706) of @TatuLund

You can also initialize the grid with an **additional boolean parameter** which will **prevent the automatic generation of columns**. This way you can still use property names when adding columns (OP does not use this, but if he did then this would be very useful information).

```
Grid<UserDto> grid = new Grid<>(UserDto.class, false);
grid.addColumn("id"); // this would not be possible witout passing the class in constructor
```

See the [API Documentation](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.3/com/vaadin/flow/component/grid/Grid.html#Grid-java.lang.Class-boolean-) of this Grid constructor for reference